# Evaluation of all positive integer ordered pairs $(n,r)$ for which $\binom{n}{r} = 2016$

Tags: binomial-coefficients

> $(1)$ Evaluation of all positive integer ordered pair $(n,r)$ for which $\displaystyle \binom{n}{r} = 120$
>
> $(2)$ Evaluation of all positive integer ordered pair $(n,r)$ for which $\displaystyle \binom{n}{r} = 2016$

$\bf{My\; Try::}$ Here $r=1$ and $n=120\;,$ Then $\displaystyle \binom{120}{1} = 120$

So $\displaystyle (n,r) = (120,1)\;\;,(120,119)$ (Using $\displaystyle \binom{n}{r} = \binom{n}{n-r}$)

Here $\displaystyle \binom{9}{3} = 84$ and $\displaystyle \binom{9}{4} = 126.$

So using Triangular numbers, Here $\displaystyle \binom{n}{r} = 120$ is valid, when $n>9$

Now when $r=2$ and $n=16\;,$ Then $\displaystyle \binom{16}{2} = 120$

So $\displaystyle (n,r) = (16,2)\;\;,(16,14)$

Now we will find when $\displaystyle \binom{n}{r}$ is an Increasing function.

So $\displaystyle \frac{\binom{n}{r+1}}{\binom{n}{r}}\geq 1\Rightarrow \frac{n-r}{r+1}\geq 1\Rightarrow r\leq \frac{n-1}{2}$

So If $r\geq 3\;,$ and $n>9\;,$ Then $\displaystyle 120=\binom{n}{r}>\binom{n}{3} = \frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{6}>\frac{(n-2)^3}{6}$

So $\displaystyle (n-2)^3<720<(9)^3\Rightarrow n<11$

So we have $n=10$ and $r=3\;,$ So we get $\displaystyle \binom{10}{3} = \binom{10}{7} = 120$

So we get $\displaystyle (n,r) = (10,3) = (10,7)$

So we get Total positive integer ordered pairs $$\displaystyle (m,n) =  \left\{(120,1)\;\;,(120,119)\;\;,(16,2)\;\;,(16,8)\;\;,(10,3)\;\;,(10,7)\right\}$$

But i did not understand How can I solve $(2)$ one.

Although we know that $\displaystyle \binom{2016}{1} = \binom{2016}{2015} = 2016$

Help me, Thanks

Comment: If $n > 2016$, there are no solutions to $\binom{n}{k}=2016$. This makes your search finite.

Comment: Here is a hint for 2016. As you noted, since $\binom{n}{r} = \binom{n}{n-r}$, it's enough for look for solutions with $0 \leq r \leq n/2$. Within this range, $\binom{n}{r}$ increases when $r$ increases. We have $\binom{24}{3} > 2016$, so the only possibilities with $r \geq 3$ will have $n \leq 23$. Also, for a fixed value of $r$, $\binom{n}{r}$ increases with $n$ ($n\geq r$), so there will be at most one value of $n$ that works for that $r$. Finally, since $7 | 2016$, you can narrow the possibilities by examining how many times $7$ appears in the numerator and denominator of $\binom{n}{r}$.

Comment: Thanks Marty, Thanks David , but i did not understand how can i found $\displaystyle \binom{64}{2} = \binom{64}{62} = 2016$

Comment: Is this a question from an on-going contest?

Comment: I have changed the formatting of the title so as to [make it take up less vertical space](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9686/290189) -- this is a policy to ensure that the scarce space on the main page is distributed evenly over the questions. See [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9730/290189) for more information. Please take this into consideration for future questions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a simple program
to search all
$\binom{n}{k}$
for
$n < 2016$.

The only solutions were the ones you found.

For a more sophisticated search,
I could use the factorization
$2016=2^53^27$,
to limit the possible values
of $n$ and $k$,
but not now.

Answer (score 2):

(2)

The fact that $\displaystyle\binom nr\leqslant \binom{n}{\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor}$ should be helpful.

If $n\leqslant 13$, there are no solutions because $\binom nr\leqslant\binom{13}{6}=1716\lt 2016$.

If $n=14$, there are no solutions because $\binom{14}{5}=2002\lt 2016\lt 3003=\binom{14}{6}$.

In the following, $n\geqslant 15$.

- For $r=1$, we have $n=2016$.
- For $r=2$, solving $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}=2016$ gives $n=64$.
- For $r=3$, we have $n(n-1)(n-2)=2^63^37^1$. Since LHS has only one integer divisible by $3$, LHS has an integer divisible by $27$. So, we have to have $n\geqslant 27$, but then $\binom{n}{3}\geqslant\binom{27}{3}=\frac{27\cdot 26\cdot 25}{6}=9\cdot 13\cdot 25>8\cdot 12\cdot 25=2400\gt 2016$.
- For $r=4$, we have $n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)=2^83^37^1$. Since LHS has only one integer divisible by $4$, LHS has an integer divisible by $32$. So, we have to have $n\geqslant 32$, but then $\binom n4\geqslant\binom{32}{4}=\frac{32\cdot 31\cdot 30\cdot 29}{24}\gt \frac{32\cdot 31\cdot 30\cdot 29}{32}\gt 30\cdot 30\cdot 10=9000\gt 2016$.
- For $5\leqslant r\leqslant\lfloor \frac n2\rfloor$, we have $\binom nr\geqslant\binom{15}{5}=3003\gt 2016$.

Therefore, the answer is
$$\color{red}{(n,r)=(2016,1),(2016,2015),(64,2),(64,62)}$$